# Write grammar for context-free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to find the grammar for the following language:

L = {a^n w w^R b^n; n >= 1, w є {a,b} and w^R is the reverse of w}

I'm really stuck on what "w є {a,b}" and "reverse of w" means.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

`w є {a,b}` means that `w` is in the set `{a, b}`, that is, `w` is either `a` or `b`. What I think they *meant* is that `w` is a string consisting of `a`s and/or `b`s.

"reverse of w" means a string consisting of the same characters as `w` , but in the opposite order. If `w = abbb`, then `w^R = bbba`.

L, then, is the set of strings starting with some number of `a`s, followed by a palindrome consisting of an even number of `a`s and `b`s, and ending with the same number of `b`s as there were `a`s preceding the palindrome.

For example, `aaaabbabbbb` would be in L: it starts with 4 `a`s, ends with 4 `b`s, and has `abba` (`w = ab`, `w^R = ba`) in the middle.

`aaaaababbbb` would *not* be in L; it has equal numbers of `a`s and `b`s at the beginning and end of the word, but `aba` cannot be decomposed into a string followed by its own reversal.